# R data.table find lags between current row to previous row

Tags: r, data.table, row, lag, shift

```
> tempDT <- data.table(colA = c("E","E","A","A","E","A","E")
+                      , lags = c(NA,1,1,2,3,1,2))
> tempDT
   colA lags
1:    E   NA
2:    E    1
3:    A    1
4:    A    2
5:    E    3
6:    A    1
7:    E    2
```

I have column `colA`, and need to find lags between current row and the previous row whose `colA == "E"`.

Note: if we could find the row reference for the previous row whose `colA == "E"`, then we could calculate the lags. However, I don't know how to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** Define `lastEpos` which given `i` returns the position of the last `E` among the first `i` rows and apply that to each row number:

```
lastEpos <- function(i) tail(which(tempDT$colA[1:i] == "E"), 1)
tempDT[, lags := .I - shift(sapply(.I, lastEpos))]
```

Here are a few variations:

**2) i-1** In this variation `lastEpos` returns the positions of the last `E` among the first `i-1` rows rather than `i`:

```
lastEpos <- function(i) tail(c(NA, which(tempDT$colA[seq_len(i-1)] == "E")), 1)
tempDT[, lags := .I - sapply(.I, lastEpos)]
```

**3) Position** Similar to (2) but uses `Position`:

```
lastEpos <- function(i) Position(c, tempDT$colA[seq_len(i-1)] == "E", right = TRUE)
tempDT[, lags := .I - sapply(.I, lastEpos)]
```

**4) rollapply**

```
library(zoo)
w <- lapply(1:nrow(tempDT), function(i) -rev(seq_len(i-1)))
tempDT[, lags := .I - rollapply(colA == "E", w, Position, f = c, right = TRUE)]
```

**5) sqldf**

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select a.colA, a.rowid - b.rowid lags
       from tempDT a left join tempDT b
       on b.rowid < a.rowid and b.colA = 'E'
       group by a.rowid")
```

Comment: Another way: `w = tempDT[colA == "E", which=TRUE]; tempDT[, v := shift(rowid(findInterval(.I, w)))]`

Comment: @Frank, it seems to be very slow when dealing with big datasets (45 mill rows). Is there anyway to speed it up?

Comment: @LeGeniusII Hm, maybe `tempDT[,  v:= shift(rowid(cumsum(colA=="E")))]`? If you post a new question (with an example that can be scaled up to any number of rows with a parameter, n), then others can also attempt to make it fast and run benchmarks to compare.