# R data.table find lags between current row to previous row (speed benchmark)

Tags: r, performance, data.table, row, lag

This question is an addition to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49142288/r-data-table-find-lags-between-current-row-to-previous-row)

```
> tempDT <- data.table(colA = c("E","E","A","A","E","A","E","A","E","A")
+                      , lags = c(NA,1,1,2,3,1,2,NA,NA,1)
+                      , group = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2))
> tempDT
    colA lags group
 1:    E   NA     1
 2:    E    1     1
 3:    A    1     1
 4:    A    2     1
 5:    E    3     1
 6:    A    1     1
 7:    E    2     1
 8:    A   NA     2
 9:    E   NA     2
10:    A    1     2
```

I have column `colA`, and need to find lags between current row and the previous row where `colA == "E"`.

@Frank has proposed two approaches:

```
 w = tempDT[colA == "E", which=TRUE]; tempDT[, v := shift(rowid(findInterval(.I, w))), by = "group"]

tempDT[, v:= shift(rowid(cumsum(colA=="E"))), by = "group"]
```

Since I'm having more than 72 million records, wondering if any other way that computes even faster.

Comment: What is the current benchmark for this?

Comment: Can you parallelize by group? What sort of machine do you have

Comment: @MichaelChirico Microsoft Azure VM, Ubuntu 16.04.3 xenial.